# How to override "nav item" class to change the background color?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I have the following in a `scss` file:

```
.nav-pills .nav-link, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #ddd 65%, #eee 65%);
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #48bfe3 65%, #85d4ec 65%);
}
```

Now I need to specify the same for the above but the background is just white. How do I create the classes?

Comment: Im not sure I understand correctly... What items you want to change? The `.nav-link`?
Can you change the gradient, or do you need to specify it on a new line?

Comment: I need to have another set of classes for 'nav-link' where the background is white.

Comment: And the links are on the exact same spot in DOM structure? Maybe I'm looking at it too easy, but doesn't this work: `.nav-pills .nav-link, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link { background: white; }`. Or you might add `!important` after the `white`.

Comment: Hi! I assume you are using bootstrap. Have you tried loading your custom css file after bootstrap.css? If that's the case you can use: `    .nav-item { background: linear-gradient(120deg, #ddd 65%, #eee 65%); }
`

Comment: nav-link.active should be nav-link::active

Comment: @Brad looks like nav-link.active works as well. What is the difference?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I'm using `nav-link` in a `sidebar` and `card.`. I only wanted to implement the gradient background for those in the `sidebar`, so I did:

```
.sidebar .nav-pills .nav-link, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #ddd 65%, #eee 65%);
}

.sidebar .nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #48bfe3 65%, #85d4ec 65%);
}
```

And it is working now.